# Reference is null when child in another bundle

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, osgi, aem, apache-felix

I have folowing classses

abstarct class:

```
@Component(componentAbstract = true)
public abstract class A implements SomeInterface{ 
    @Reference
    private ConfigurationManager manager;
    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
       manager.getTimeout();
    }
}
```

first child:

```
 @Component(
            enabled = true,
            immediate = true,
            inherit = true,
            metatype = true,
            label = "***",
            description = "***"
    )
    public class A1 extends A {...}
```

second child:

```
@Component(
        enabled = true,
        immediate = true,
        inherit = true,
        metatype = true,
        label = "********",
        description = "*************"
)
public class A2 extends A {...}
```

`A` and `A1`  resides in same bundle but `A2` in another.

when `Apache Felix` instantiate `A1` `manager.getTimeout();` row executes successfully but for `A2` this row is cause of `NullPointeException`.

How to solve this problem?

**update:**

```
@Component(
        enabled = true,
        immediate = true,
        metatype = true,
        label = "***"
)
@Service(ConfigurationManager.class)
public class ConfigurationManager {
@Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        valueDelimiter = PropertiesUtil.toString(componentContext.getProperties().get(PROPERTY_VALUE_DELIMITER), PROPERTY_VALUE_DELIMITER_DEFAULT);
        valueDelimiter = Pattern.quote(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(valueDelimiter));//read value from osgi config
        ...

        LOG.info("Service reconfigured: {}", toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: It can't execute for either, `manager` is never initialized and thus it is `null`. I think maybe you're executing on threads or something and you think it is executing first. You can debug to make sure.

Comment: I noticed it in debug.

Comment: Where are you initializing `manager`?

Comment: Initially it was! = null and then then it null in same base class

Comment: It can't be != null if you never assign it. Show us where you initialize it or how it is initialized.

Comment: What does the generated XML look like? Which DS annotations are these? It does not look like OSGi specification ones. Perhaps bnd or Felix?

Comment: @BJHargrave `apache-felix` tag?

Comment: @m0skit0 Can you concretize question? A annotated as Component and as Service and have annotated Activate method

Comment: @m0skit0 Does my update relevant to your request?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sorry, I still don't see how is `manager` initialized.

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't understand you request. Clease clarify it in details.

Comment: I don't know what I should clarify about "initializing a variable"...

Comment: @m0skit0 it is reference. felix injects this service

Comment: Then it is not "injecting" it.

Comment: for first child inject but second - not